# Is Kazran Sardick an anagram for something?

Tags: doctor-who

Michael Gambon's character in the 2010 Doctor Who Christmas special "A Christmas Carol" had the anagrammy-sounding name "Kazran Sardick". I remember jotting down a few ideas on paper, but never came up with anything the was an obvious hit.

Is there an anagram to this name, or is it just an odd-sounding name? If he were to have a son Shelnec Sardick...

Comment: I see what you did there...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Suffice to say, probably not.](http://wordsmith.org/anagram/anagram.cgi?anagram=Kazran%20Sardick&t=1000&a=n)

Unless it's "A Czars Dark Kin".  The other 190 potential anagrams don't really work very well.  Most do, however, involve the word 'czar'.

Comment: I'm partial to "Czar And Ska Irk"...perhaps an indication of the writer's aversion to both the Russian monarchy and Jamaican music?

Answer (score 2):

Kazran Sardick...I have a theory...I believe that it is a direct homage to Charles Dickens.

Chesren Saldick would be an anagram of Charles Dickens.  I can see Mr. Moffat doing an anagram, then denunciating some of the consonants to make a better sounding name.

Just my 2 cents worth...And i guess I owe you some change.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's an anagram, but you're right that it sounds like it should be meaningful.

This article has a theory about Judaism: http://deepgrey.org/dr_who_the_matt_smith_christmas_special

Comment: Wow...just...wow. Whenever I read stuff like this, I can't help but hear it in the voice of Wallace Shawn. Which is ironic, I suppose. Or Comic Book Guy from the Simpsons.

Comment: Yes, I'm inclined to believe that Kazran is a [Tzadik](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tzadik), which I have learnt is pronounced "Tsardick".